# Automated process Data Studio

Tags: python, automation, looker-studio

Is it possible to create an automated process where a script (could be Python) could grab a Data Studio template, replicate it and then connect to a different data source?

My concern about using 1 dashboard for all 300 clients is the load time to filter and update the dashboard, plus restricting access to the client to only see their data.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not supported.

There is no API to programmatically copy reports or reconnect data sources.